# CKeditor textarea is disabled up until when I click the source button?

Tags: ckeditor

I am really confused about CKEditor. When I load or reload the page the CKEditor is automatically disabled on the first request of the page. Whenever I click the source button, and again click source for normal editing, the content area is enabled and I can write only then.

Comment: Please provide some code, so we can see what you are doing. -- Sounds to me like the editor cannot be initialized in the correct way. This means you are probably not waiting until the page has loaded, so the script cannot find and initialize the editor correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue for a textarea that was hidden when page loads...and on some action say a button click...it was displayed...I had exactly the same behavior.

I was initializing CKEDITOR.replace('control') at page load.

I later changed it on show event of the control and that worked for me.

Something like

```
$('#ControlId').show();
$('#ControlId').val(question[1]);
CKEDITOR.replace('ControlId');
```