# Disabled text area

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, ckeditor

I have an editor instance that opens inside a modal dialog (on a jquery.dialog("open")).

The problem is that **sometimes** in Chrome browser, the editable area comes disabled by default (and the user cannot write any text). I can do two thing to enable it :

1. Click the 'source' button twice
2. Resize the editor

Is this a known problem? I cannot find any sources/solutions on it.

Please note that Firefox browser has never created this problem.

Also this question addresses this problem [CKeditor textarea is disabled up until when I click the source button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881224/ckeditor-textarea-is-disabled-up-until-when-i-click-the-source-button?rq=1) but no answer is given.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

My html

```
<textarea name="problem" id="problem" class="ckeditor" ></textarea>
```

My initialization code:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.problem;
editor.setData(''); 
editor.resize( '100%', '80', true );
```

My config.js :

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {

    config.toolbar = 'MyToolbar';

    config.toolbar_MyToolbar =
    [
        { name: 'document', items : [ 'Preview','Print','-','Templates' ] },
        { name: 'clipboard', items : [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ] },
        { name: 'editing', items : [ 'Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','-','SpellChecker', 'Scayt' ] },
        { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','Subscript','Superscript','-','RemoveFormat' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote','CreateDiv',
        '-','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock','-','BidiLtr','BidiRtl' ] },
        { name: 'links', items : [ 'Link','Unlink', ] },
        { name: 'insert', items : [ 'Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar','PageBreak' ] },
        { name: 'styles', items : [ 'Styles','Format','Font','FontSize' ] },
        { name: 'colors', items : [ 'TextColor','BGColor' ] },
        { name: 'tools', items : [ 'Maximize', 'ShowBlocks','Source'] }
    ];
    config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre';
    config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;link:advanced';
    config.scayt_autoStartup = true;
    config.skin = '/kama';
    config.entities_processNumerical = 'force';
};
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here is also a screen shot of what is happening this time in Firefox 21.0:

[image]

The difference between the Chrome error is that the 2 steps listed above to enable the editor didn't work. I had to refresh the page in order to make it work.

Here is the actual [html](http://jsfiddle.net/a7vPa/) code when this occurred.

Please also note that there where no console errors.

Comment: "Please provide some code, so we can see what you are doing.". JSFiddle sample would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Failure to provide more information such as code will likely result in the same fate as that other question - it either gets closed or dies in apathy.

Comment: @Reinmar I have provided some details

Comment: I have the same problem on my implemetation. To fix this, I initialize  CKEDITOR with source mode and when user focus on I switch mode on HTML.

Comment: @EpokK Does it also work in FF?

Comment: Yes it work on Firefox.

Comment: @EpokK I'm afraid this solution didn't work for me.